# I can't seem to find the solution to a DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js v13 and I've gotten the hint that I probably have an issue with the `message.delete()` functionality. However, I've tried surrounding it in a `try/catch statement` but I still get the error. I'm not sure how it's triggered but it still deletes the message but keeps the message still visible to the author.

My Code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    if(message.channel.id != ChannelID) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [wrongChannel] }) && message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
    switch(args[0]) {
        case "help":
            client.commands.get('help').run(client, message);
            break;
        case "ping":
            client.commands.get('ping').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "ban":
            client.commands.get('ban').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "kick":
            client.commands.get('kick').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "mute":
            client.commands.get('mute').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        default:
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [err] });
            try {
                await message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
    }
    try {
        await message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Discord Bots\test\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Discord Bots\test\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (D:\Discord Bots\test\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:205:5)
    at async Message.delete (D:\Discord Bots\test\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:709:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (D:\Discord Bots\test\index.js:72:13) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/891701894559461407/messages/891720458859331585',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

This is meant to check if the command is being done in the **wrong** channel, then it'll send them an embed I've made and delete the message. If not but they've typed the command correctly, after typing it correctly it'll be deleted and same vice versa. After typing it incorrectly it will send an embed and delete it. Without the try/catch it would just keep it visible to the author and crash the bot. But with the try/catch it just sends the error then keeps the message visible to the author but not to others. Meaning it works and it does delete, just not to the author and throws that error.

Comment: Hi ! You are using `await`, but is it in an `async` function effectively waiting for a promise before continuing it's job ?

Comment: I was told to add `await` but it didn't make a difference

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that in your code, you delete it twice, what for ? If the `default:` part (first call) is done, then it does not surprise me you get a `404` error at second call. It doesn't deal with the fact that the message stays visible, I know

Answer (score 0):

```js
        default:
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [err] });
            // first try/catch
            try {
                await message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
    }
    // second try/catch
    try {
        await message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

In the first [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block, the [`default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#can_i_put_a_default_between_cases) case of your [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement is to delete the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) if none of the conditions above is met. That is fine. The code works and the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) gets succesfully deleted.

However in the second one, you are trying to [`delete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) that same [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). However, it doesn't exist anymore as the [`default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#can_i_put_a_default_between_cases) case in the switch block will **always** [`delete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)  it, therefore there is no reference to it and Discord throws an [`DiscordAPIError`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#types-of-errors). Therefore, you cannot call [`message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) again.

To fix it, just delete the second [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block:

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    if(message.channel.id != ChannelID) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [wrongChannel] }) && message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
    switch(args[0]) {
        case "help":
            client.commands.get('help').run(client, message);
            break;
        case "ping":
            client.commands.get('ping').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "ban":
            client.commands.get('ban').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "kick":
            client.commands.get('kick').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "mute":
            client.commands.get('mute').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        default:
            // will always delete if conditions aren't met
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [err] });
            try {
                await message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
    }
```

Let me know if this works out.

**EDIT: If you want the bot to delete the user message regardless of correctness**

```
if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    if(message.channel.id != ChannelID) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [wrongChannel] }) && message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
    switch(args[0]) {
        case "help":
            client.commands.get('help').run(client, message);
            break;
        case "ping":
            client.commands.get('ping').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "ban":
            client.commands.get('ban').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "kick":
            client.commands.get('kick').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        case "mute":
            client.commands.get('mute').run(client, message, args);
            break;
        default:
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [err] });
    }
    // will always delete
    try {
        await message.delete({ timeout: 1000 });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
```

Comment: Issue is, that's only if they type it incorrectly, what if they type it correctly? it won't delete. Unless if i just add to every case the `try/catch` statement. Kinda overflown but i guess that works. EDIT: It doesn't throw an error anymore and I've added the `try/catch` to each case. However, discord has some weird issue where it would still show me my message even though its deleted and it requires me to `CTRL + R` to refresh discord so it could disappear.

Comment: In that case, you can move the code in the default case to the outer scope. This ensures that the message will always be deleted.

Comment: Responding to your comment, it was originally like that, but if i type it incorrectly, it threw an error, crashed the bot and kept the message

Comment: Yes i know that, re-read my comment

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Same error in the title